# preventDefault() in Event Handler Suppresses Change Detection

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, javascript-framework

I created an attribute directive that is designed to work with HTML `<input>` elements. On every key press, I wish to disable the browser's default behavior and implement my own special behavior.

Therefore, in my directive I implemented a `keydown` event handler where I call `preventDefault()` on the passed in event object, and set the `<input>` element's value by assigning to `this.el.nativeElement.value`.

However, this has the unexpected consequence of preventing changes to the `<input>` element's value from propagating to underlying form control objects (i.e in reactive forms).

I've created a (somewhat contrived) minimal reproduction of this issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-directive-event-handler-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a case of the wrong tool for the job.

If one wishes to directly write to a native element in the DOM and maintain two-way change detection they should implement the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface.